# addRow method of exceljs doesn't add data

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I'm using [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) and [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) here to load data from a csv file into the excelsheet that've created.

Now matter what I try the addRow method doesn't create data in the file.

```
var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('addresses');    
fs.createReadStream('./templates/dummyAddresses.csv', 'utf8')
    .pipe(csv({ quoteColumns: false }))
    .on("data", function (data) {
        worksheet.addRow(data);        
    })
    .on("end", function () {
        console.log("template loaded");
        cb(null)
    });
```

Any leads would help